# How to change the country name and then draw the global map?

Tags: julia, vega-lite

I got the dataset like following:
[image]

I want to make a world map and see which country have higher mean salary, maybe represent through density or sth else, like density higher means the mean salary is higher, I tried do that with vegalite but I always got the error:
[image]

then I realized this data have country name like this:
https:

[image]

Ru means russia, NZ means new zealand …Is there any way that I can covert these into the complete country name? and where have I got wrong on this map code?
Can someone help me with that please?
Thanks for any help:)

I just wanna say thank you to all people that offered me suggestions!!!!!!
I have successfully change my country name, but I don't know how to make a map for each country and show which country have higher mean value, Can someone give me some advices please?
[image]

Comment: Please add data and code to the text. If the links somehow don't work anymore (images removed) then the question has no future value at all.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).  Links to external sites might get lost (in time), and your first 2 pictures just contain TEXT, so why not post the TEXT?

Comment: sorry im relatively new to this web, when I post at the first time its saying that I need to reach some condition to be able to post the picture, but somehow I can post the pic now

Comment: You should not post a picture when it only contains text ...

Comment: Great question, and thanks for accepting! It is better to ask your new question (how to make a world map plot) in a separate post so others will see it. Also, it's better to copy and paste from the terminal, rather than take a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These abbreviations resemble [ISO 3166 alpha-2 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes). The Julia package [Countries.jl](https://github.com/cjdoris/Countries.jl) is great for converting ISO standards:

```
julia> using Countries, DataFrames

julia> ds = DataFrame(company_location=["RU", "US", "NZ"], Mean=[1580000, 142000, 122000])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ company_location  Mean
     │ String            Int64
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │ RU                1580000
   2 │ US                 142000
   3 │ NZ                 122000

julia> ds.country_names = [x.name for x in get_country.(ds.company_location)];

julia> ds
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ company_location  Mean     country_names
     │ String            Int64    String
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ RU                1580000  Russian Federation
   2 │ US                 142000  United States
   3 │ NZ                 122000  New Zealand
```

Alternatively, you could make your own dictionary that maps codes to full names. This could be useful if the abbreviations are non-standard, or if you're working with something else in general:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> ds = DataFrame(company_location=["RU", "US", "NZ"], Mean=[1580000, 142000, 122000])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ company_location  Mean
     │ String            Int64
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │ RU                1580000
   2 │ US                 142000
   3 │ NZ                 122000

julia> country_codes = Dict("RU" => "Russia", "US" => "United States", "NZ" => "New Zealand");

julia> ds.country_names = getindex.(Ref(country_codes), ds.company_location);

julia> ds
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ company_location  Mean     country_names
     │ String            Int64    String
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ RU                1580000  Russia
   2 │ US                 142000  United States
   3 │ NZ                 122000  New Zealand
```

(I couldn't find an obvious way to pass multiple indices to a dictionary, but [this post on the Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-can-i-access-multiple-values-of-a-dictionary-using-a-tuple-of-keys/56868/3?u=ashlin_harris) shows a working method, which I've used in my example)

Comment: "couldn't find any Julia package for converting between these", maybe you can use: https://restcountries.com/v3.1/alpha/RU ?  (source: https://restcountries.com/#api-endpoints-v3-code )